# Postgres check existence of any array element within JSONB column with another array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am working on PostgreSQL 13.9. I want to check an array within a JSONB with another input array to see if there was any overlap of elements between the two then return true in the sample SQL below

```
 select 
  '  {
  "id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
  "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
  "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
  "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
}'::jsonb @? '$ ? ((@.id2[*] ?| ["5","7"]))'::jsonpath
```

> I am getting error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "|" of jsonpath
> input LINE 7: }'::jsonb @? '$ ? ((@.id2[*] ?| ["5","7"]))'::jsonpath
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 153

Same works when i compare with a single element as shown below and returns "true"

```
select 
  '  {
  "id1": ["9"],  "id2": ["5"],
  "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
  "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
  "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
}'::jsonb @? '$ ? ((@.id1 == "9") && (@.id2[*] == "5"))'::jsonpath
```

I am not able to identify what i am doing wrong. I want to do in a perf efficient manner. So do not want to write with multiple OR like

```
(@.id2[*]== "5" || @.id2[*] == 7)
```

Any pointers on what i am doing wrong will be of great help

Comment: `?|` is not an operator of the jsonpath language.  At least not as implemented by PostgreSQL, maybe someone else's interpretation of jsonpath does include it.  There is a PostgreSQL `?|` operator, but it is a regular PostgreSQL operator, not inside jsonpath.

Comment: "I want to do in a perf efficient manner."  Without a working example, you have no idea of whether it is performant or not.  Get something that actually works, then worry about performance.

Comment: See here [Filter Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH): *Table 9.51. jsonpath Filter Expression Elements* for what expression is allowed in a filter and what the expressions do. `|` is not one of them.

Comment: select 
  '  {
  "id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
  "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
  "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
  "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
}'::jsonb @? '$ ? ((@.id2[*] == "5" || @.id2[*] == "7"))'::jsonpath 
Above works. My criteria is formed dynamically with many jsonb attributes on which search can be performed. I have a gin index on this jsonb column. My opinion is we need to do things in a single hit with minimum I/O as possible to have better perf. I could have the above as a separate array column and do a  "&& " with input to check for overlap. It will need additional I/O & comparision

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer using jsonb_path_query from here [JSON functions/operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) *Table 9.49. JSON Processing Functions*:

```
select jsonb_path_query( 
  '  {
  "id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
  "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
  "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
  "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
}'::jsonb, '($.id2)') ?| array['5','7'];
?column? 
----------
 t

select jsonb_path_query( 
  '  {
  "id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
  "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
  "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
  "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
}'::jsonb, '($.id3)') ?| array['5','7'];
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, `?|` you're trying to use exists as plain PostgreSQL operator, but it's not offered by this implementation of JSONPath, therefore cannot be used in such expression. Also, you can't use array or object literals in the expression, so `["5","7"]` can't be used in there, either.

If what you have is a `jsonb` object you want compare with another, you can pass the whole thing as a variable into the expression. The `@?` operator doesn't allow that, but [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.17.1.1.1) does. Once you have both objects in the JSONPath, they can both use [`[*]` accessor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH):

```sql
select jsonb_path_exists('{"id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
                           "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
                           "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
                           "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
                          }'::jsonb,
                         '$.id2[*]?(@==$var.id2[*])',
                         '{"var":{"id2":["5","7"]}}'::jsonb);
```

| jsonb_path_exists |
| --- |
| t |

Or you can add it in:

```sql
select jsonb_path_exists('{"id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
                           "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
                           "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
                           "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
                          }'::jsonb||'{"var":{"id2":["5","7"]}}'::jsonb,
                         '$.id2[*]?(@==$.var.id2[*])');
```

| jsonb_path_exists |
| --- |
| t |

Or you can access the key with a regular `->` and use your `text[]` array with `?|` directly:

```sql
select 
  '  {
  "id1": ["5"],  "id2": ["5"],
  "id3": ["cc","dd" ],
  "id4": "15",   "id5": "11",
  "id6": "2",  "id7": ["12","18"]
}'::jsonb->'id2' ?| '{5,7}'
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| t |

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6vPAIkVi)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select exists (
  select from jsonb_array_elements('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb)
  where value::int = any(array[1, 4])
);
```